# Plotly Dash taking too long to load the js files

Tags: javascript, python, plotly, plotly-dash

Below is the snapshot from devtools. My Dash app is taking too long because of these js scripts, is there any way to speed it up. May be cache these on gunicorn side or server side?

[image: Below is the snapshot from devtools]